# Update UITableViewCell via setHighlighted

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, highlight

My UITableView is made of custom cells.

What I need to accomplish is, if a user taps on a cell, they can see the new imageView and when they lift their finger, the cell updates to the new image. Visa versa.

Right now, if I tap down on a cell, I see the selected image, but when I lift, it stays as unselected.

```
 // This is done in my custom cell subclass
 - (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated
 {
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted animated:animated];

    if (highlighted)
    {
        self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageSelected"];
    }
    else
    {
        self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageDeselected"];
    }
 }
```

Comment: I use, sender.selected = !sender.isSelected; for when I want a button work like a toggle / switch.

Comment: Could do it in a didSelectRowAtIndex maybe - good luck, good question. Give collectionViews a try as well. Much more creative things you can do with those and work much the same as a TableView

Answer (score 1):

Additionally toggle the view in `setSelected:animated:`.